# $P(S|X,Y)$ where $S=X+Y$

Tags: probability

I have the following question:

Let's say we have $X \in N(\mu_x,\sigma_x)$ and $Y \in N(\mu_y,\sigma_y)$ and construct $S=X+Y$. We then draw $x_i$ and $y_i$ from their distribution.

What is $P(S=s_i|X=x_i,Y=y_i)$?

I think it's one since $X,Y$ is given, however I'm not sure. Any ideas?

(P stands for probability)

Comment: What is the meaning of $P(S|X,Y)$ ? S is not an event

Comment: It's? I think of it as a sum of two r.v's and therefore can be seen as a r.v.

Comment: $P$ stands for probability ?

Comment: yes exactly, P stands for probability

Comment: I read "knowing $X$ and $Y$, what is the probability that $S$"

Comment: I realized that the question is worded badly. It shouldn't be "drawn", I'll update the question.

Comment: The notation is terrible. What is it you are testing? "$P(S)$" makes no sense. You would have to say something like "$P(S<0.5)$" or "$P(S=0.2)$". These are values, not events.

Comment: Are you asking for the distribution of $S$ knowing $X$ and $Y$ ?

Comment: It was confusing, sorry for that. I have updated the question.

Comment: I believe that the question asks what is the probability of $S=s_i$ given $X=x_i$ and $Y=y_i$. Since it is already given that $S=X+Y$, 

$$P(S=s_i|X=x_i,Y=y_i)=1 \quad \textrm{iff} \quad s_i=x_i+y_i  $$ 
otherwise it is zero.

Comment: So I guess you mean that it's Indicator function of $s_i = x_i + y_i$ i.e. $1($s_i = x_i + y_i$)$

Comment: I am not so sure about the indicator function since the definition of indicator function, $I_A(w)$, requires a set $A$, and a value $w$. However as pointed out by @eric-towers dirac delta function is more suitable:

$$P(S=s_i|X=x_i,Y=y_i)=\delta(s_i-(x_i+y_i))$$

Delta function is defined as $\delta(x)=1$ if $x=0$ otherwise zero.

Comment: @tempx Indicator functions are perfectly suited to the task at hand. Recall that one can define $\mathbf 1_A(\omega)$ as you indicated but also $\mathbf 1_Q=1$ if $Q$ holds and $\mathbf 1_Q=0$ otherwise, for any property $Q$, for example $\mathbf 1_{42\ \text{is prime}}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\delta_{s_i -(x_i + y_i)}$, where $\delta_x$ is the [Dirac delta "function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).  This use of $\delta_x$ suggests that $P$ is the wrong tool to do whatever it is that you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Would it be diffrent if it was $p(S=s_k | X, Y)$? ($S = X+Y$)

Comment: Yes?  This new expression is undefined.  Neither "$X$" nor "$Y$" is an event.  How do you condition on things that are not events?  Are you able to ask in words what you want?  "I want to know the probability of <some event> given that all of <list of antecedent events> are true."

Comment: I have the model $X \in N(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2)$ and $Y \in N(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2)$. However these are not observed, we only observe their sum, $S = X + Y$. Let's say we observe one outcome $s_k$. I want to compute $p(s_k, X_k, Y_k, \theta)$, where there is the parameters for the model. We have $p(s_k, X_k, Y_k, \theta) = p(s_k | X_k, Y_k, \theta) \cdot p(....)$, where $p(....)$ is some uninteresting probability. Now, Im not sure how to compute $p(s_k | X_k, Y_k, \theta)$. Hope it helpt to clarify

Comment: Any probability of a tuple with $s_k$, $X_k$ or $Y_k$ as a component is zero.  The probability that a normally distributed random variable or the sum of two such variables takes a particular value is $0$ (assuming the variance is positive).  Something that is not vacuous is $P(m \leq s_k \leq M \mid \theta)$, the probability that the sum of the two random variables is between (given) $m$ and $M$, assuming a particular parameter vector.

Comment: Okay, but if we instead had categorical distribution (or some other dicrete one) instead of normal?

Comment: Do you intend that $X_k$ is a different distribution for every $k$?  I.e., do you have a fixed distribution from which to draw $X$ once $\theta$ is specified or do you have a sequence of (potentially) different distributions?

Comment: Let's say that X is drawn from the same distribution and $\theta$ encodes everything you need to know about the distribution in terms of parameters.

Comment: Then you're almost ready to post a new question that asks what you want to know.  You have a parameter vector $theta$, which specifies parameters for two distributions $X$ and $Y$.  Then for $x$ drawn from $X$ and $y$ drawn from $Y$, you wish to know (pick one:) $P(m \leq x+y \leq M \mid \theta)$, the PDF of $x+y$, the CDF of $x+y$, or perhaps something else.